# Drawer Navigator with shared header among all children

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

This is about a React Native + React Navigation issue.

In my project I need a top-level DrawerNavigator so as a shared header among all screens, so that when the drawer opens it stays on top of the header. Best solution I've come up so far was a DrawerNavigator with all of its routes as a StackNavigator with same header config, but that just seems to hacky, ugly and non-performatic, as I think the header would be re-rendering everytime. Has anyone done anything similar? Thanks in advance.

**Router.js**

```
export const RegisterStack = StackNavigator(
    {
        Register: {screen: Register},
    },
    {
        mode: 'modal',
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'My title',
        }
    }
);

export const HistoryStack = StackNavigator(
    {
        History: {screen: History},
    },
    {
        mode: 'modal',
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'My title',
        }
    }
);

export const FavoritesStack = StackNavigator(
    {
        Favorites: {screen: Favorites},
    },
    {
        mode: 'modal',
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'My title',
        }
    }
);

export const CardsStack = StackNavigator(
    {
        Cards: {screen: Cards},
    },
    {
        mode: 'modal',
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'My title',
        }
    }
);

export const AgreementStack = StackNavigator(
    {
        Agreement: {screen: Agreement},
    },
    {
        mode: 'modal',
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'My title',
        }
    }
);

export const createRootNavigator = () => {

    return DrawerNavigator({
        Register: {
            screen: RegisterStack,
        },
        History: {
            screen: HistoryStack,
        },
        Favorites: {
            screen: FavoritesStack,
        },
        Cards: {
            screen: CardsStack
        },
        Agreement: {
            screen: AgreementStack,
        },
    })

};
```

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends Component {

    render() {

        const Layout = createRootNavigator();

        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Layout style={styles.main}/>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try doing it the other way? StackNavigator with a single screen containin DrawerNavigator

Comment: Yeah, but this way the drawer will open under the header :/

Comment: https://github.com/paraswatts/DrawerNavigatorReactNative check this example I made

Comment: Nice @ParasWatts! But wouldn't this way the top-level stacknavigator header stay above the drawer?

Comment: yes that will stay above the drawernavigator

Answer (score 0):

Okay I actually got this to work, what you have to do is make a stackNavigator inside the drawer navigator, the drawerNavigator is able to see inside the stackNavigator and navigate between the stacknavigator screens. Using the contentComponent.  Once you have done this you can put the shard header inside the stackNavigator.

```
const PrimaryDrawer = createDrawerNavigator({
  PrimaryStack,
}, {
  contentComponent: PrimaryDrawerContentComponent,
})

const PrimaryStack = createStackNavigator({
  Feed,
  Home,
}, {
})

import _ from 'lodash'
export default class PrimaryDrawerContentComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={_.keys(navigation.router.childRouters.PrimaryStack.childRouters)}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <DrawerItem
              routeName={item}
              navigate={navigation.navigate}
              icon={icons[index] ? icons[index] : null}
            />

      )}
      keyExtractor={item => item.key}
    />
  )
 }
}


const DrawerItem = ({ routeName, navigate, icon }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.button}
      onPress={() => { navigate(routeName) }}
    >
      <Image
        source={icon}
      />
      <Text style={styles.text}>{routeName}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```